# Nvidia Shadowplay with AMD GPU&CPU

Tags: nvidia-geforce

Few months ago I had a method to run Shadowplay of Nvidia, I have AMD GPU&CPU, but I forgot how I had it working.. I googled about it but all I found is creating shortcut of "nvidia share.exe" and adding -shadowplay as argument

do someone know how can I accomplish it? I have nvidia geforce experience folder, it has everything I believe.

Or maybe if there's a modded nvidia geforce experience that would install on AMD without checking for NVIDIA gpu?

Comment: Windows Game Bar has similar functionality, why can't you just use that? While in a game press Win + G and select the record icon in the "Capture" window, usually the top left item by default...

Comment: Can't, I need to use NVIDIA Shadowplay specifically